# Encoding problem in ASP.NET MVC + MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-2, encoding

I have some trouble showing right single quote from mysql database.

Screenshot:

[image]

This problem appears only when I deploy the application on a server.
If I start the application locally, connected to the database on the server, it's ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the encoding is set different on the server than your system.  Check what the default encoding is on your system and then the server.  The MySQL will just use what is set in the DB not the system.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.Default.ToString() returns System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding on both sides